# Backbone change model and change the properties of the new models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Backbone has a model that will change when a property is changed to the new models also have even default properties also change these.

Recovery model and change the property

```
var model =  window.collections.elements.get('c1');
// property change css.background.value = red
var vals = model.get('css')['background']['value'] = 'red';

model.set( vals );
model.trigger('change');
```

I add a new property is also changed

```
// add new model and inherits the model that made the change
var new_m = new Maker.Models.Widget.H2();
window.collections.elements.add(new_m);

console.log( window.collections.elements.get('c2').get('css') );
// property change and new model change css.background.value = red
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L8cjfged/

Console

UPDATE

Solution 1

McGarnagle thank you

Solution 2

var model =  window.collections.elements.get('c1');
var newModel = $.extend( true, {}, model );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently Backbone is not smart enough to clone the default values -- it saves and re-uses the same instance (of course this works fine for value types, but not for reference types).

To get around this problem, I would use the "initialize" function to set the "css" default, like this:

```
Maker.Models.Widget.H2 = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync: function () { return false; },
    initialize: function() {
        if (!this.has('css')) {
            this.set('css', { 
                'background' : {
                    value : '',
                    type  : 'text',
                    script : ''
                } 
            });
        }
    },
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ueq87c85/3/